# How to remove comment count in blog?

Tags: php, wordpress

How I can remove comment count from my blog posts. I am using Creativo theme.

I have tired

```
.comments-count {display: none;}'''
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

There's another CSS instruction from the theme itself with higher priority than yours. So to move up in the CSS hierarchy, be more specific with your instruction.

This works:

```
.post_meta li.comments_count {
    display: none;
}
```

You should use the Chrome or Firefox developer tools to inspect the element and see why your CSS is not applied. Most times you will see a higher CSS rule that takes precedence and you can fix accordingly.

Comment: Great to hear that. If this was the correct answer, please mark it as the solution to your question so you will help people who will look for this in the future

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty vague/would need to see the HTML, but one thing that might work (assuming you're actually applying the class "comments-count" to the blog posts), would be to add an !important; modifier.

```
.comments-count{display: none !important;}
```

also, personally I sometimes have had issues with the "none" modifier -- you could try:

```
.comments-count{display: hidden !important;}
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your theme has different classes for the comments count. You can apply the following CSS to remove comments count from single post.

```
.single-post .post_meta .comments_count {
  display: none;
}
```

To remove the border from the li after removing comment count, use this CSS.

```
.single-post .post_meta li:nth-child(2) {
    border-right: none;
}
```